# How can you combine search filters to show items that match either one criteria OR another, rather than items that must match all criteria?

Tags: search-facet, sxa-search

We have a list of events in the Sitecore. Some events occur on specific dates while others occur all year round. We can show either events that fall within a date range using start and end dates and the date range filter. We could alternatively show events with the 'Anytime' field checked. However we would like to be able to show events within a date-range combined with events that are considered anytime. It seems Sitecore only wants to reduce the number of events through search criteria but not allow you to look for events that fall within 2 conflicting search criteria.

Is there a way to combine the search fields so that search results displays for instance items where "Field A" is true OR items where "Field B" is true?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the `Scope Query` and `Item Query` are going to severely limit AND/OR logic typically expected in search results. Think of those as filters to reduce results by location (path in the tree), template, and field value (like a checkbox). Doing more than 2 levels of conditions is not likely to be possible. The use of the `+` character will mark the condition as **must** (AND) otherwise it will be **should** (OR).

You can confirm the generated query by reviewing the Sitecore or Solr Search logs.

I'm not sure the outcome of adding a UI component to do additional filtering, but if your scope query was like the following:

```
+template:{51ed5851-1a61-4dae-b803-6c7fae6b43d8};
custom:EventStartDate|[NOW TO *];
custom:EventEndDate|[NOW TO *];
custom:isfeatured|true;
```

This would be the generated query:

```
(
  _template:(51ed58511a614daeb8036c7fae6b43d8) 
  AND 
  (
    eventstartdate_tdt:([NOW TO *]) 
    OR 
    eventenddate_tdt:([NOW TO *])
    OR 
    isfeatured_b:(True)
  )
)
```

If I only wanted the featured checkbox to be associated with the event start date but not the event end date then I would have to consider building something custom.

If you want to cycle through changes quickly you can make use of SPE.

```
$props = @{
    Index = "sitecore_sxa_master_index"
    ScopeQuery = "+template:{51ed5851-1a61-4dae-b803-6c7fae6b43d8};custom:EventStartDate|[NOW TO *];custom:EventEndDate|[NOW TO *];custom:isfeatured|true"
}

Find-Item @props
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this;

```
var dateReangePredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<EventSearchResult>();
dateReangePredicate = dateReangePredicate.And(t => t.startDate > DateTime.Now);
dateReangePredicate = dateReangePredicate.And(t => t.endDate > DateTime.Now);

var anytimePredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<EventSearchResult>();
anytimePredicate = anytimePredicate.And(t => t.AnyTime == true);

var query = searchContext.GetQueryable<EventSearchResult>().Where(dateReangePredicate).Where(anytimePredicate);
```

Notice the "False" in the anytimepredicate. This signals to make OR with the previous predicate. So this should translate to something like:

if((start > now && end < now) || isAnytime == true)

When your code runs check your Search logs and you can view the exact solr query being generated, should help you debug.

This is a great blog post about search and predicates: https://soen.ghost.io/a-re-introduction-to-the-contentsearch-api-in-sitecore-part-2/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Gene, can you explain the purpose of anytimePredicate.Or({Lambda Expression})?

Comment: Chet, that adds the predicate to our original query:

The first query dateReangePredicate  (start > now && end < now)
the Second predicate  anytimePredicate.Or(lamda) is isAnytime == true

Since I declared the anytime predicate PredicateBuilder.False it should combine to be:

if((start > now && end < now) || isAnytime == true)

The article I linked goes into greater depth and explanation of predacities:  https://soen.ghost.io/a-re-introduction-to-the-contentsearch-api-in-sitecore-part-2/